# ESP TCP servers COR Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error

Tags: javascript, tcp

I have two wemos d1 mini which both connects to my router and creates separate TCP servers, and I want to extract LDR data from say Server 1 from server 2. I'm using http GET to try to retrieve the data, but since my servers are separate, I get COR No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried adding:

```
server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Everywhere I can think of but couldn't resolve the problem.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
(Code is modified from Rui Santos: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-dht11-dht22-temperature-humidity-web-server-arduino-ide/)

```
#include "ESPAsyncWebServer.h"
#include "ESPAsyncTCP.h"
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h"

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "WiFi";
const char* password = "Pass";

int LDRpin = A0;
// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);

String readLDR(){
  return String(analogRead(LDRpin));
}



const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title> LDR value</title>
  <style>
    html {
     font-family: Arial;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0px auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    h2 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    p { font-size: 3.0rem; }
    .units { font-size: 1.2rem; }
    .ldr-labels{
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      vertical-align:middle;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>ESP8266 LDR</h2>

  <p>
    <i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i>
    <span class="ldr-labels">Ldr</span>
    <span id="ldr">%LDR%</span>
  </p>
  
</body>


<script>
setInterval(function ( ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      document.getElementById("ldr").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/ldr", true);
  xhttp.send();
}, 100 ) ;

</script>
</html>)rawliteral";

// Replaces placeholder with DHT values
String processor(const String& var){
  //Serial.println(var);
  if(var == ":LDR"){
    return readLDR();
  }
  return String();
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Connect to Wi-Fi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Route for root / web page
  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);
  });
  server.on("/ldr", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/plain", readLDR().c_str());
  });

  // Start server
  server.begin();
}
 
void loop(){
  
}
```

Comment: The CORS headers need to be set at the **server**, not the client.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean as there are two servers. So the ESP connected to LDR makes a server that stores and updates the LDR value, and another ESP's server uses https GET to retrieve the data.

Comment: The CORS headers need to be set in the server code that prepares the **response** to the request, not in the browser JavaScript code.

Comment: I get Class AsyncWebServer has no member named sendHeader.

Comment: Am I missing a library?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I swear I tried this million times but what ever reason it didn't work back then and now it does...
I added:

```
DefaultHeaders::Instance().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Worked like a charm